# How to define plural quantifiers in terms of more primitive concepts?

Tags: logic

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575948/the-quantifier-most) earlier today and was trying to figure out how to determine one way or the other whether a *most* quantifier can be implemented using plural quantifiers. Then I read the [SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/) on plural quantifiers and now I'm really confused as to what these things mean.

If we allow sets of truth values, then there's a straightforward way to *encode* statements in ordinary first order logic as expressions involving sets. What is the right way to do this for plural quantifiers?

I've attempted to include below what I *think* plural quantifiers mean based on the article but there are few things I'm unsure about.

- Treatment of singleton plural individuals
- Extending singleton-taking predicates to plural individuals

I'm specifically going after the formal language called *LPFO+* in the article.

The article goes into some detail about using plural individuals as a type of non-set collection to avoid Russell's paradox. I'm not using them for this purpose; I'm just looking at the cases where a domain of discourse that is a set has already been nailed down.

---

*This is my attempt to define run-of-the-mill higher order quantifiers (of which first-order quantifiers are a special case) by constructing sets of truth values. I'm then attempting to do the same thing for plural quantifiers. I'm thinking of first-order logic as a special case of higher-order logic where the set quantified over is always $D$.*

First a word on notation.

Let $\varepsilon$ be the empty set.

Let $\prec$ be a logical relation insisting that the left argument *is contained in* the right argument.

Let $[\cdot]$ be the Iverson bracket, which sends true sentences to $1$ and false sentences to $0$.

Let $\phi[x:=v]$ refer to the well-formed formula formed by replacing $x$ with $v$ in $\theta$.

Let $\text{Set}[xx]$ refer to the set corresponding to value of the plural variable $xx$.

Let $D$ be a set, the sometimes-implicit domain or universe of discourse of first-order logic.

Let $\phi$ be a well-formed formula, possibly with free variable $x$. Let $\Phi$ be a well-formed formula, possibly with free variable $xx$.

Following the notation in the SEP article, let $x$ be a singular variable and $xx$ be a plural variable.

If we have the language of set theory, we use that to define the meaning of $\forall$ and $\exists$ in classical higher order logic.

$$ \forall x : D \mathop. \phi \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \{[\phi[x:=t]] \mathop. t \in D\} \in \{\varepsilon, \{1\}\} $$

$$ \exists x : D \mathop. \phi \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \{[\phi[x:=t]] \mathop. t \in D \} \in \{\{1\}, \{0,1\}\} $$

In *LPFO+*, some predicates treat plural entities collectively and others do not.

let $\Phi$ be an arbitrary wff where $xx$ is a free variable. We can define existential and universal plural quantification in terms of our earlier definitions.

$$ \exists xx \mathop. \Phi \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \exists t : D \to 2 \mathop. t \neq \varepsilon \land \Phi[xx := t] $$

$$ \forall xx \mathop. \Phi \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \forall t : D \to 2 \mathop. t \neq \varepsilon \to \Phi[xx:=t] $$

However, we have an implicit conversion of sorts between predicates taking singular arguments and predicates taking plural arguments. Predicates taking singular argument can also be applied *distributively*.

If $P$ is a predicate taking a singular argument, then

$$ P(xx) \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \forall t : \text{Set}[xx] \mathop. P(t) $$

Let $ww$ be a free plural variable in the below expressions. If $\theta$ is a wff with a singular free variable $x$, then

$$ \theta[x:=ww] \;\;\text{is equivalent to}\;\; (\forall x \mathop. x \prec ww \to \theta) $$

I think this is sufficient to nail down the truth conditions of a formula, open or closed, involving plural quantifiers.